# nhibernate parameters binding order potential bug?

Tags: nhibernate, debugging, linq-to-nhibernate

i am using latest nhibernate 3, my query:

```
iqt = rps.Terminals.GetQuery().Where(x => x.NetProtocol.Id == 4);
var res = iqt.OrderBy(x => x.Attributes[124]).ToList(); 
//ITerminal have IDictionary<long,string>
```

When i look to the log file i see generated sql:

```
SELECT terminal0_.ID       AS ID4_        ,
  terminal0_.ALIAS          AS ALIAS4_     ,
  terminal0_.TTYPE_ID       AS TTYPE3_4_   ,
  terminal0_.IP_ADDRESS     AS IP4_4_      ,
  terminal0_.STREET         AS STREET4_    ,
  terminal0_.LOCATION       AS LOCATION4_  ,
  terminal0_.MODEL_ID       AS MODEL7_4_   ,
  terminal0_.NODE_ID        AS NODE8_4_    ,
  terminal0_.NETPROTOCOL_ID AS NETPROTO9_4_,
  (SELECT (xml_desc(terminal0_.street,'UA'))
     FROM terminals
    WHERE terminals.id =terminal0_.Id
  ) AS formula1_,
  (SELECT (xml_desc(terminal0_.location,'UA'))
     FROM terminals
    WHERE terminals.id =terminal0_.Id
  ) AS formula2_,
  (SELECT (xml_desc(terminal_models.description,'EN'))
     FROM terminal_models
    WHERE terminal_models.id = terminal0_.MODEL_ID
  ) AS formula3_
   FROM TERMINALS terminal0_,
  TERM_ATTRIBUTES attributes1_
  WHERE terminal0_.ID        =attributes1_.TERM_ID
AND attributes1_.ATTR_ID     = :p0
AND terminal0_.NETPROTOCOL_ID=:p1 //-> bug here it bind p1 with 124 value but correct p0
ORDER BY attributes1_.VALUE ASC;

:p0 = 4 [Type: Int64 (0)],
:p1 = 124 [Type: Int64 (0)]
```

I think nhibernate could not correctly resolve parameters bind order with sub selects.
Is there nhibernate guru or developer to confirm it and say how to fix it?

Tnaks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does look buggy.

Please open an issue including a small reproduction project or test case at http://jira.nhforge.org

Comment: Thanks for response i post it to http://jira.nhforge.org but i cannt create reproduction project...

Comment: @SanjaMelnichuk: why? If you can't reproduce your defect, it won't get fixed.

Comment: I cant because it used my database tables etc, but problem reproducing each time

Comment: @SanjaMelnichuk: And? Just remove everything that's not related to the problem. The DB is not needed, just the classes, the mappings and the query.